# SQL Query INNER JOIN Syntax

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. I have a syntax error and cannot seem to get the SQL Query System to agree with it:

```
select t.tracktitle from tracks t
inner join titles ti
inner join artists ar
if (ar.artistname = "The Bullets
", 'yes', 'no')
on ti.titleid = t.titleid;
```

I am trying to find all tracks by the artist name, "The Bullets". My tables resemble the following:

**Tracks**

```
TitleID, TrackNum, TrackTitle
```

**Titles**

```
TitleID, ArtistID, Title
```

**Artists**

```
ArtistID, ArtistName, Region
```

My question is having to find all tracks by the artistname, "The Bullets", and my attempt at the query:

```
select t.tracktitle from tracks t
inner join titles ti
inner join artists ar
if (ar.artistname = "The Bullets
", 'yes', 'no')
on ti.titleid = t.titleid;
```

The Problem is that I need a YES (if it matches the artistname) or NO if it does not match the artistname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement is the issue, as that type of syntax for SQL is called a `case` statement. That said, based on what you want, you should move that up to the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Tracks.tracktitle
FROM tracks Tracks
INNER JOIN titles Titles ON Titles.titleid = Tracks.titleid
INNER JOIN artists Artists ON Artists.artistid = Titles.artistid
    AND Artists.artistname =  'The Bullets';
```

If you wanted to bring over all artists and have something like an identifier row (your "yes" or "no"):

```
SELECT Tracks.tracktitle
    ,CASE Artists.artistname
        WHEN 'The Bullets' THEN 'yes'
        ELSE 'no'
    END AS isTheBullets
FROM tracks Tracks
INNER JOIN titles Titles ON Titles.titleid = Tracks.titleid
INNER JOIN artists Artists ON Artists.artistid = Titles.artistid;
```

This is how you do an `if` statement like you were attempting with SQL syntax. Notice that I no longer include `ar.artistname` in the JOIN, because you want to bring back all artists, and just identify those that are 'The Bullets'.

Comment: How do I have a YES or NO column based on the match?

Comment: @user2948897 - haha i literally just added that in case you wanted to know. :)

Comment: @user2948897 - thats my fault, i typoed the alias. updated my answer, and updated the aliases to be a bit more transparent (helpful when keeping track of multiple joins)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t.tracktitle 
from tracks t inner join titles ti 
     on ti.titleid = t.titleid
     inner join artists ar 
     on ar.artistid =  ti.artistid
      and ar.ArtistName = 'The Bullets'
```

If you need to check if record exists:

```
select t.tracktitle 
from tracks t inner join titles ti 
     on ti.titleid = t.titleid
     inner join artists ar 
     on ar.artistid =  ti.artistid
      and ar.ArtistName = 'The Bullets'
limit 1
```

Empty result (no rows) - 'yes', one row - 'yes'

Comment: How do I have a YES or NO column based on the match?

Comment: @user2948897 You use a [`CASE ..`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression, in the column list, between `select` and `from`.

Comment: All rows which you will have in result will be 'yes'. No rows - not result.

Comment: Example was added to answer

Answer (score 1):

Mistake number 1 - you are joining from one table to another without specifying any fields.  The correct syntax is:

```
 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.fieldname = table2.fieldname
```

Mistake number 2 - this is invalid sql:

```
if (ar.artistname = "The Bullets ", 'yes', 'no')
```

You want something like

```
where ar.artistname = "The Bullets "
```

instead.